# Check and clear last value

Tags: java

I have a method like this:

```
public boolean wasUserInactive() {
    boolean result = userInactive;
    userInactive = false;
    return result;
}
```

This works, but is there a “smarter” way to code this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This method satisfies two concerns:

1. mark users as active
2. return the last status of inactivity

This should be two separate methods so as to not violate SRP and enable checking of that status without resetting it.

`wasUserInactive` should be `isUserInactive` and just `return userInactive;`. Additionally there should be a method resetting the inactive status to false.

Don't introduce quantum behaviour in your code, where observing a state changes it!